# Hide a div When Clicked outside of the div

Tags: jquery, css, html-select

I try to create a custom drop-down. I want to make it works as default drop-down like hide all the option when i clicked outside of the div. As far as i try to make it, i can hide all option when i clicked outside of the div (inside the document). But when i clicked on Browser URL or Title of the page, drop-down doesn't hide.

Here is my Code: https://jsfiddle.net/db82jnqv/

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#dvStatsDate").click(function () {
        if($("#customSelectBox").is(":visible"))
           $("#customSelectBox").hide();
        else
            $("#customSelectBox").show();
    });
    
    $("#customSelectList > li").click(function (){
       $("#statsDate").text($(this).find("span").text());
        $("#customSelectBox").hide();
    });
    
    $(document).click(function(event){
        if(!$(event.target).is("#dvStatsDate,#statsDate")){
            $("#customSelectBox").hide();
        }
    });

});
```

```css
.dvCustomSelect {
    width: 236px;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
}

.dvCustomSelect > div {
    display: table-cell;
}

.dvCustomSelect > div:last-child {
    width: 80%;
}

.dvCustomSelect .divSelect {
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.dvCustomSelectbox {
    position: relative;
}

.dvCustomSelectLbl > div {
    width: 100%;
    color: #555555;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
    min-height: 21px;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.dvCustomSelectLbl > div i.fa {
    float: right;
}

.dvCustomSelectOptions {
    left: 0px;
    top: 100%;
    width: 204px;
    z-index: 221;
    display: none;
    margin-top: -4px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.dvCustomSelectOptions ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;
}

.dvCustomSelectOptions ul li {
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    background-color: white;
}

.dvCustomSelectOptions ul li:not(:last-child):hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(0, 120, 163);
}

.dvCustomSelectOptions ul li:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

.dvCustomSelectOptions ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='dvCustomSelect'>
  <div>Date</div>
  <div class="dvCustomSelectbox">
   <div class="dvCustomSelectLbl">
      <div id="dvStatsDate"><span id="statsDate" class="selectDate">Today</span> <i class="fa fa-sort-down"></i></div>
   </div>
   <div class="dvCustomSelectOptions" id="customSelectBox">
      <ul id="customSelectList">
         <li><span>Today</span></li>
         <li><span>Yesterday</span></li>
         <li><span>This Week</span></li>
         <li><span>Last Week</span></li>
         <li><span>This Month</span></li>
         <li><span>Last Month</span></li>
         <li><span>This Quarter</span></li>
         <li><span>Last Quarter</span></li>
         <li><span>This Year</span></li>
         <li><span>Last Year</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want that when user clicked on anywhere of Browser, drop-down will be hide.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want that functionality? How does it effect the end user? If they are clicking on the title, or the URL they are clearly leaving your site anyway, I don't see a logical reason why you would want to write this functionality into your code, but please enlighten me if I'm wrong :-)

Comment: blur doesn't fire unless you focus on something else in the document.

Comment: `$(window).on('blur', function(){
        $("#customSelectBox").hide();
    });`   https://jsfiddle.net/db82jnqv/2/

Comment: @buschschwick, it is the requirement of my project. As default select behave like this, custom one should be like default one. And when user click on browser url bar, it doesn't mean he leave the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the behaviour you are expecting, hiding element when `window` loses focus:

```
$(window).on('blur', function(){
    $("#customSelectBox").hide();
});
```

### -DEMO-

Comment: it works when i clicked on the address bar. But when i clicked on current page title bar, bookmark bar, it doesn't worked.

Comment: I'm sorry but there is no event afaik to handle this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that it is possible to do everything you are asking.

You could use the `$(window).blur()` as A.Wolff suggested, but this only works when you click on something that can receive focus such as the addressbar input. Just clicking on part of the browser window won't make the window blur, so I don't think you are going to obtain this functionality with your clicking requirement.

If you loosen the click requirement, you could just hide the popup on mouseleave instead. If not, then A. Wolff's answer is probably as good as it gets using jquery/javascript.

**JSFIDDLE** https://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/db82jnqv/4/

```
$("#customSelectBox").mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).hide(); 
});
```

Also updated your show/hide logic to use .toggle

```
$("#dvStatsDate").click(function () {
    $("#customSelectBox").toggle();
});
```

Comment: If he's concerned with the window he could do that binding on the body.

Comment: Cannot open it more than once, because you are not reshowing list. Anyway, this is different behaviour than OP seems to expect

Comment: @A.Wolff, you are correct. I was using customselectlist instead of customselectbox. The user can now open it more than once.

Comment: @Brino, When i hover on the custom select box, then leave the select box, it hide the select box. **it hides only when user click outside of the custom select box**.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you there.

```
$.fn.clickOff = function(callback, selfDestroy) {
    var clicked = false;
    var parent = this;
    var destroy = selfDestroy || true;

    parent.click(function() {
        clicked = true;
    });

    $(document).click(function(event) { 
        if (!clicked) {
            callback(parent, event);
        }
        if (destroy) {
            //parent.clickOff = function() {};
            //parent.off("click");
            //$(document).off("click");
            //parent.off("clickOff");
        };
        clicked = false;
    });
};

$("#myDiv").click(function() {
    alert('clickOn');
});

$("#myDiv").clickOff(function() {
    alert('clickOff');
});
```

[**FIDDLE!**](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/tHCUB/)

Comment: this does not work when clicking on the browser window, title, or address bar